# Concatenating numbers returns different values

Tags: sql, concatenation, teradata, sqldatatypes

The output of my code is showing two different things that don't make sense based on the code. I'll do my best to illustrate since it seems I can't upload pictures from my computer in SO with guided mode...

```
state      cvmo       unique_code     total
IL         201701      95316          80,162.31
IL         201701      91304          21,315.69
IL         201,701     90035          63,989.21
IL         201701      96735          54,557.76
```

So you can see that the cvmo column has two different values of 201701 and 201,701 and I'm not sure why. The output I'm getting for the total of IL is about double what it should be so this makes me wonder if the total are getting multiplied by two because of this. Also, each unique_code only is only paired with either 201701 or 201,701.

I have a member table with cvmo taken straight from a database and all are in the form of 201701.

Next, the following code that is used on the total table:

```
,case when extract(month from svc_from_dt) < 10
        then trim(extract(year from svc_from_dt)) || '0' || trim(extract(month from svc_from_dt))
        else trim(extract(year from svc_from_dt)) || trim(extract(month from svc_from_dt))
        end as cvmo
/*This is also in the form 201701*/
```

The output above is taken when joining the member table on cvmo and on a unique member key.

Comment: so you are saying you dont want  `201,701`. Just provide with input sample and desired o/p

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what's wromg, but the calculation to get YYYYMM is way too complicated, use this instead:

```
to_char(svc_from_dt, 'yyyymm') -- 'YYYYMM' string
```